# Touch automatically displays context menu on text boxes in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, touch, chromium

I'm running an application which is in the cloud on Chromium Browser on Linux (Raspberry Pi OS).

When I click on a textbox (where the text is already there) it selects the text for half of the second and then it automatically shows the context menu preventing me from modifying the content. (This also happens in Windows in Chrome).

This does not happen in the desktop app and in Firefox on Windows. I was wondering why that is? Is there a setting to change this? I noticed that behaviour works as expected if you hold the finger on the text box for 2 seconds however the single-finger touch just highlights and shows the context menu which is not practical.

I would essentially want to swap this the other way around; touch and hold to simulate right click and click to select.

This only happens in Chrome. I do not have much control of the cloud application therefore I was wondering if there is any particular setting in Chrome which controls this behaviour. I tried changing the system settings on windows. I went to chrome://flags and disabled the following:

```
Omnibox rich entity suggestions; Send tab to self omnibox sending animation; Touch UI layout; 
Touch initiated drag and drop; Enable experimental fling animation; Enable resampling input events;
Context menus show full URLs; Show autofill predictions; 
Omnibox preserve default match against async update; Experimental system keyboard lock;
Omnibox on device head suggestions; Select HW overlay strategies; WebUI tab strip; 
Select which UI to use for translate bubble; WebUI tab strip demo options; Scrollable TabStrip;
Omnibox on-focus suggestions; Substring matching for autofill suggestions; 
Omnibox local entity suggestions; Omnibox Zero Suggestions on SERP / On-Focus Query Refinement;
Omnibox Experimental Keyword Mode; Filtering scroll predictions; Focus mode; 
Zero-copy rasterizer; Omnibox Experimental Suggest Scoring; 
Enable Probing on Navigation Predictor Isolated Prerenders; Hardware Media Key Handling;
Media Session Service; Audio Focus Enforcement;
```

I also went into the developer settings to see if there is anything in there but was unsuccessful.

I also tried the google extension to block right-click behaviour however it did not work.

I would like to go back to developers of the cloud app and ask them to correct this but the only question is why it works on other browsers.

I tried other browsers on Raspberry Pi but they nowhere near the performance of chromium.